# remainder of separable metrizable space

Tags: general-topology

A remainder of a Tychonoff space is a $bX\setminus X$, where $bX$ is a compactification of $X$. Does every separable metrizable space has a separable metrizable remainder?

thanks,

Comment: Do you mean: Does every separable, metrizable space have at least one compactification with a separable, metrizable remainder? (Use `\setminus` to get the set difference symbol.)

Comment: Crossposted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/110291/remainder-of-metrizable-seperable-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *yes*. Let $D=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a countable dense subset of $X$, and let $d$ be a compatible metrix bounded by $1$. Define

$$\varphi:X\to[0,1]^\omega:x\mapsto\left\langle d(x,x_n):n\in\omega\right\rangle\;;$$

it’s not hard to check that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto $\varphi[X]$. Now let $bX=\operatorname{cl}\varphi[X]$, where the closure is taken in $[0,1]^\omega$; clearly this is a compactification of $X$, and since $[0,1]^\omega$ is a separable metrizable space, so is $bX\setminus X$.

**Added:** The space $[0,1]^\omega$ is known as the [Hilbert cube](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertCube.html). It is universal for separable metrizable spaces or, equivalently, for second countable $T_3$-spaces.

Comment: May be clear, but how can we say since $bX$ is separable metrizable, so is $bX\X$. Is it just true for Hilbert Cube?

Comment: metrizability is hereditary but separability is not.

Comment: @ege: A metrizable space is separable iff it is second countable, and second countability *is* hereditary.

Comment: @Emil: Thanks for answering: I was a bit slow getting back to this.

Comment: Again sorry but, compatible metrix bounded by 1 is the same with dicsrete metric or not? I could not find the definition of compatible metric.

Comment: @ege: If $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a metrizable space, a metric $d$ on $X$ is *compatible* if it generates the topology $\tau$; *compatible* is short for *compatible with the given topology*. By definition there is at least one compatible metric for a metrizable space, and given any metric $d$ on a space, it’s a basic exercise to show that there is a bounded metric that generates the same topology. Thus, every metrizable space has a compatible bounded metric, and by scaling we can take the bound to be $1$.

Comment: I think,   $d_{1}=minimum\{1,d\}$ is a  bounded metric by 1 and generates the same topology. And also, these are equivalent metrics. Is it right?

Comment: @ege: Yes, that’s right. Another way to do it is to define $$d_1(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}\;.$$

Comment: Again sorry, but how we can say $\phi$ is one to one and continuous. I think to show to one to one, we need some properties of the metric $d$. Take any $x and y$ which are different.Then there exists a $n$ such that $d(x,x_{n})$ not equal to $d(y,x_{n}) ( but how can I show)

Comment: @ege: Since $D$ is dense in $X$, there is a sequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\to x$. If $d(x,x_m)=d(y,x_m)$ for all $m\in\Bbb N$, then $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\to y$, and therefore $x=y$.

Comment: @Brian: Sorry I didn’t notice this earlier, but in your answer, “second-countable $T_4$” and “separable metrizable” are the same thing, one is not more general than the other.

Comment: @Emil: Of course. I must have been asleep.

Comment: thanks so much for your help.